# Loading image from database in mvc.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a database and a dbinitializer class that populated the database with test data.  one of my columns of one of my tables are for storing a string path to images.  ie: Image="~/Content/Images/example.img"

then my view model is supposed to render the image for each item in the table.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <img style="width:200px;height:250px;" src="@Url.Content(item.Image)" alt="@item.Name" />

}
```

This exact method works in my normal mvc app but when i tried to emulate the exact same code in my core app the images arent rendering.  Does anyone know why I could be getting this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET core, static files are served from only the `wwwroot` folder by default. That means if you try to access a file from Contents/Images, which is your root, it won't work.

The good news is, You can configure the static file location as you wish. So update your `Configure` method in startup.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
                                                           ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
     // Your existing code goes here

     app.UseStaticFiles();

     app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
     {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
              Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Content/Images")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/Images")
     });
}
```

Now these images can be accessed from the browser like this `yourSiteName/Images/imageFile.png`

Now you can fix your view code to get image from this path.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/"+item.Image)"  />
    </div>
}
```

Assuming `item.Image` value for each item in the collection has some value like this `MyImage.png` and you have an image called `MyImage.png` located at the `Contents/Images` which is in your application root (`not in the wwwroot directory`)

You may also consider moving the images to the wwwroot directory because the ASP.NET team added that directory for purposes like this ( static assets).

Comment: Right after I made this post I remembered seeing the wwwroot folder and altered my item.Image string but I can't seem to make it work with that path.  ie: ~/wwwroot/images/cardImages.

I think there may be some other subtle nuance that I'm not aware of?

Comment: The css file and everything else is in this default root folder and I'd like to roll with the conventions of Core.  I was advised by a buddy that I should use core so I'm attempting to migrate my project

Comment: As i explained in the answer, if your images are inside the `wwwroot`  directory, You can access the items inside that via a GET request (simply try to access the resource in the browser). This is because asp.net core allows static file serving from that location. If you have those images in Content folder (on app root like pre asp.net core apps style), you need to make the update to `Configure` method.